# Trouble with Spanish letters and jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8

I am creating a quiz for conjugating Spanish verbs. I have a jQuery .js file that is populating the form with conjugated Spanish verbs. The verbs will eventually be fed with AJAX from remote files that store the conjugated verbs.

After doing a lot of research I made sure that I have this in the HTML file :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

and

```
<script src="js/verb-quiz.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

for the link to the JavaScript file.

I am still getting weird characters for accented letters. I am stumped. I can't test the users entries against the correct verb form if there are these weird characters. I tried using HTML ASCII code (which is a real pain), but still had issues when displaying the characters.

Comment: Please post your actual jQuery code.

Comment: Check the Content-Type HTTP header.

Comment: This isn't my exact code - too lengthy to show here, but this ends up with the same result of a goofy character for the é

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").html("coméis");
 var test = $("p").html();
 alert(test);
});

Both the <p> tag and the alert have the goofy character and not the é

I am not sure what "check the Content-Type HTTP header" means. Isn't that addressed in my original post?  I also tried this:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />

but it still does the same thing.

Comment: could be data storage charset issue

Comment: What is weird is that I get the same result if I run the file locally or if I test it on my hosting server. I also added this to the .htaccess

AddCharset utf-8 .js

From some post I saw.

Comment: Which editor do you use to write the JS code? Are you sure the document itself is written in utf-8 encoded?

Comment: I use Notepad++. It turns out that I needed to add the <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" /> to the HTML data file that AJAX was retrieving. Thanks all.